# Elasticsearch - incorrect aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the max value of one field on elastic-search 2.4.1, but it different to the actual one.

Looks like ES is doing approximate aggregation, but not sure whether maximum will have the error.

When execute

```
POST http://192.168.100.211:9200/bt211/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "grades_stats": {
      "max": {
        "field": "4999"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Got

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 245831,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [ ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "grades_stats": {
      "value": 4746809856
    }
  }
}
```

But if I query one specified doc

```
POST http://192.168.100.223:9200/bt211/_search
{
      "_source": [
        "4999"
      ],
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "_id": [
            "AV5fg6y-7V3dJ49T89qT"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

It will response

```
{
  "took": 238,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bt211201709082",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AV5fg6y-7V3dJ49T89qT",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "4999": 4746809900
       }
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

The value of "4999" is `4746809900`, which is bigger than the result of "max" aggregation.

Is there any way to get the accurate result for max in Elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you get when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/bt211201709082/_mapping/test/field/4999` ?

Comment: @Val it returns:
{
bt211201709082: {
mappings: {
test: {
4999: {
full_name: "4999",
mapping: {
4999: {
type: "float"
}
}
}
}
}
}
}

is it may be due to the error of float?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure it would work better with a `long``

Comment: I got it, thank you @Val